# How to add namespace to custom route extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Im using routes.add instead of routes.maproute (which has a namespace arg)
because I extended the Route Class. 
I need to add namespace on the routes because one of my Areas has the same controller name
within the site.
My problem is I dont know where to put the namespace..

```
public class CultureRoute : Route
{
     public CultureRoute(string url, object defaults, object constraints, RouteValueDictionary dataTokens)
            : base(url, new RouteValueDictionary(constraints), dataTokens, new MvcRouteHandler())
        {
        }
}
```

Global.asax

```
routes.Add("Default", new CultureRoute(
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}));
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var dataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary();
var ns = new string[] {"MyProject.Controllers"};
dataTokens["Namespaces"] = ns;

routes.Add("Default", new CultureRoute(
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    null /*constraints*/,
    dataTokens
));
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: (Previously created a custom route but that wasn't necessary).  This should do the trick.  At least it does in MVC 4 and most probably MVC 3

```cs
Route defRoute = new CultureRoute ("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
            new SomeRouteHandler());
if( defRoute.DataTokens == null )
      defRoute.DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary();
defRoute.DataTokens.Add("Namespaces", new string[] { "MVCApp.WebUI.Controllers" });
        routes.Add(defRoute);
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who were hunting for a solution for this:

You first need a constructor that accepts the DataTokens argument, and pass that through to the Route constructor.

For example, I was using a DomainRoute class I picked up online, which did not have the additional arguments required to pass through to Domain. So I simply implemented a constructor similar to the base Route [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679815.aspx):

```
public DomainRoute(string domain, string url, object defaults, object constraints, object dataTokens)
              : base(url, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), new RouteValueDictionary(constraints),new RouteValueDictionary(dataTokens),new MvcRouteHandler())
{
              Domain = domain;
}
```

Next, if you have overriden your [GetRouteData](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/2.6.4-mono-.net-core/System.Web/System/Web/Routing/Route.cs.htm) method, you **must** return the DataTokens in your RouteData return value. In order to figure this out, I had to look in the Route.cs source code (THANK YOU JAVA2S).

```
RouteData data = new RouteData(...);
RouteValueDictionary dataTokens = DataTokens;
if (this.DataTokens != null) {
   RouteValueDictionary rdDataTokens = rd.DataTokens;
   foreach (var token in dataTokens)
      rdDataTokens.Add (token.Key, token.Value);
   }
}
return data;
```

Now simply put in your namespaces in dataTokens["Namespaces"] as per Fleents post.

Regards,
Daryl

Comment: quite some time ago ... I think you are using the class by Maarten B., correct? Adding the namespaces as shown above does not work for me then. It would be adding them as RouteValueDictionary into a RouteValueDictionary then. I am currently extending that, to have a subdomain to area routing.

Comment: Definitely a long time ago... to the extent that I don't even know what the original problem was or what I was solving. =)